# Pass variable from function to template

Tags: views, theming

I want to pass a variable from a mymodule_preprocess_node(&$vars) to my template file.
Something as simple as the following:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $vars['node_type'] = 'some_type';
}
```

I trying to pass this variable to a zone--content.tpl.php file.

PS: Cleared all the caches :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass variables to the zone template, you need to preprocess the zone, not the node

```
function mymodule_preprocess_zone(&$vars) {
  $vars['node_type'] = 'some_type';
}
```

Comment: Still $variables['node_type'] is undefined in the template.

Comment: You might have to resort to doing this in your theme, and implementing `hook_alpha_preprocess_zone()` (making the assumption you're using Omega)